# Does "HereMaps" supports Indoor Mapping implementation in Xamarin.Forms (Android/IOS/UWP)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk

**Does "HereMaps" supports Indoor Mapping implementation in Xamarin.Forms (Android/IOS/UWP)  with the following requirements :**

We are trying to explore Indoor mapping implementation for an office building. Can you please confirm if the following use cases are possible and do you provide any SDK or support for Xamarin Forms?

1. Create own floor maps for indoor (OR) Use CAD/.PNG file to create own floor map for indoor
2. IPS (aka bluedot)
3. Define our POI’s on the indoor map
4. Static / Dynamic navigation
5. Turn- By-Turn directions
6. Share location

Please share your solutions for the above requirements using Here Maps If possible.

Comment: https://www.here.com/?form_id=2227&form_category=contact-us&cta_id=1_contact-us&detailed_source=www.here.com%2F

Comment: I have sent query "here.com/ ", waiting for the response from them.